# Can a Bash extended globbing pattern be used to match a path NOT containing specific characters

Tags: regex, bash, glob

In a bash script I would like to find files whose path does not contain a subdirectory with a *"double extension"*. For example, if I am looking in subdirectories of `/my/home` for `path/to/my/file` and the following existed, the script would locate the first one only:

```
/my/home/subdirectory.1/path/to/my/file
/my/home/subdirectory.1.2/path/to/my/file
```

This is a simplified example: the `1` and `2` may be any string; the key point is they are like file extensions (i.e. separated by periods).

I can use `ls`

```
$ ls /my/home/subdirectory.*/path/to/my/file
```

but this returns both - I'd like to replace `.*` with `.[^.]*` but that's a regex and globbing doesn't use regex. I've tried extended globbing but I can't get it to work (*I'm happy to admit I am unfamiliar with extended globbing*):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls /my/home/subdirectory.!(.*)/path/to/my/file
```

I know I can use `find` to do this like so:

```
$ find /my/home/subdirectory* -regex "/my/home/subdirectory.[^.]*/path/to/my/file"
```

but I would expect a glob to be quicker. However, having read up on this, I think this is beyond the abilities of Bash's globbing, extended or otherwise. But I thought it a good question that could be worth discussing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
ls /my/home/direcectory.+([!.])/path/to/my/file
```

which will match one or more non-`.` characters in the extension.

Comment: Note that a carat (`^`) can be used in place of the exclamation point.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ls /my/home/subdirectory!(.*.*)/path/to/my/file
```

or

```
ls /my/home/subdirectory.!(*.*)/path/to/my/file
```

depending on whether you would like directories without extensions to be matched or not.

Comment: I like your answers becasuse they are easy to understand, however @chepner's answer also ignores the `/my/home/directory./path/to/my/file` and is therefore a little stricter.